# I get a error when using HoughCircles with Python OpenCV that a module is missing

Tags: python, opencv

I have a small test code block trying to process a simple photo with a ball in it:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("b.jpg")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray,cv2.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT)
```

When I try to run this I get:

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'HOUGH_GRADIENT'

I've been installing and reinstalling for two days trying to figure out whats wrong.
Any help or pointers would be appreciated!

Comment: which version of OpenCV you are using?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

add this line : `import cv2.cv as cv` and change `circles`

`circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray,cv.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT)`

i.e. `cv.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT` in place of `cv2.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT`

This will solve the `AttributeError` that you were getting but still you'll get a type error, you'll have to provide arguments for `dp` and `minDist`
(arguments at pos 3 and pos 4) and that you can give accordingly.(Here I've given 1 and 10)

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
import cv2
import cv2.cv as cv
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("test.jpg")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray,cv.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 10)
```

also please see a similar problem solved here:

http://answers.opencv.org/question/1497/errors-with-cv2houghcircles/

Answer (score 9):

try

circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray, **cv2.cv.CV_HOUGH_GRADIEN**T, 1.2, 75)

works, to me

Comment: More recent OpenCV changed the interface. the correct idiom is now: ```circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1.2, 75)```