# Track circles in video OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(1):

    # Take each frame
    _, frame = cap.read()
    frame = cv2.medianBlur(frame,5)
    cimg = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

    circles = cv2.HoughCircles(frame,cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,20,
                                param1=50,param2=30,minRadius=0,maxRadius=0)

    circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))

    for i in circles[0,:]:
        # draw the outer circle
        cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(0,255,0),2)
        # draw the center of the circle
        cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),2,(0,0,255),3)

    cv2.imshow('frame',cimg)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I am trying to find circles, but my code fails `OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scn == 1 && (dcn == 3 || dcn == 4))`. Any idea why? In addition, how to get coordinates of a circle?

Answer (score 0):

The flag you pass to cvt Color should be cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY instead of cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR - you want convert to grayscale to have single channeled image instead of RGB 3 channeled image and that's what assertion says. (look at the [docs](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html#houghcircles) to see what paramaters you need, an input image is clearly a *8-bit, single-channel, grayscale input image.*)

Rest of the code looks ok and is an answer to second part of your question.

**EDIT:** (after OP having another problem  with passing constant):
After changing cvtColor constant we had following code:

```
cimg = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(cimg,cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,20,
                            param1=50,param2=30,minRadius=0,maxRadius=0)
```

which actually caused another problem:

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'HOUGH_GRADIENT'

Since I'm working with OpenCV mostly with C++ and not with Python, I solved it in different way. I tried to find number equivalent of CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT constant. In turned out to be located in opencv\sources\modules\imgproc\include\opencv2\imgproc\types_c.h:

```
enum
{
    CV_HOUGH_STANDARD =0,
    CV_HOUGH_PROBABILISTIC =1,
    CV_HOUGH_MULTI_SCALE =2,
    CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT =3
};
```

That is why we can use following snippet instead of predefined constant:

```
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(cimg,3,1,20, param1=50,param2=30,minRadius=0,maxRadius=0)
```

Comment: Hm I get `OpenCV Error: Bad argument (The source image must be 8-bit, single-channel) in cvHoughCircles,` now. I tried to solve it by following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22241474/i-get-a-error-when-using-houghcircles-with-python-opencv-that-a-module-is-missin, but failed..

Comment: Why don't you try passing 3 there (literally, an integer 3) @good_evening. So the call will look like circles = cv2.HoughCircles(frame,3,1,20,  param1=50,param2=30,minRadius=0,maxRadius=0)

Comment: thanks, but I'm still getting `OpenCV Error: Bad argument (The source image must be 8-bit, single-channel)` :(

Comment: Opss, beacuse we pass still the same argument. Try this: circles = cv2.HoughCircles(cimg,3,1,20, param1=50,param2=30,minRadius=0,maxRadius=0)

Comment: thanks, it works! however, there are so many circles in the window, that nothing can be seen basically :/

Comment: That's another problem but it is really a general one. It depends on the image you're passing. Try filtering out the results by some radius threshold.

Comment: it's video from camera